# Adding third party jar tools

Tags: android, jsoup

I finished an app like a month ago which uses the JSoup jar in it. commonsWares pointed out to me that I need to remove the jar file from the build path and create a libs folder for proper usage.

I removed it from the build path and created a folder called libs and placed the jar file in there. Is this correct?

The android project is returning error because it can't see the JSoup library. So how do I do this to ensure its all visible and working well?

A screenshot of what I have done is below:

[image: libs]

Comment: "Is this correct?" -- Assuming that you are on the latest version of the Android SDK tools and the Eclipse ADT plugin, yes. "The android project is returning error because it can't see the JSoup library." -- that is a useless statement. You have not indicated if this is a compile-time or run-time error. Nor did you provide the details of the error, such as the stack trace if it is a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not be on the latest ADT.
The latest ADT should just pick up any jar in your library.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you move a jar file's location you need to update the build path. In Eclipse, you should right click on the project, select *Build Path* then *Configure Build Path*. Then just select the *Libraries* tab, and then *Add Jar*. Find your jar file and select it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Since r17, SDK automatically handle this for you (suppose use libs folder), check out the [changelog](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html): _Added feature to automatically setup JAR dependencies. Any .jar files in the /libs folder are added to the build configuration (similar to how the Ant build system works)._ If you still prefer the old way, [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) is the hint: _If you are still referencing jar libraries manually instead of putting them under libs/ be aware of the following:_